# Убрать атрибут disable при смене радио кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 радио кнопки `#is_group_1` и `#is_group_0`.
При выборе `#is_group_1`, у селекта `#product_select` должен убираться атрибут `disabled`. А при выборе `#is_group_0`,у селекта `#product_select` должен добавляться атрибут `disabled`. Код работает в 1 направлении почему то.

```
var productType = $('#is_group_1');
    var productSelect = $('#product_select');
    productType.change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        productSelect.prop('disabled', true);
    },
    function() {
        productSelect.prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Пробовал так, но так не работает тоже

```
 var productType = $('#is_group_1');
    var productSelect = $('#product_select');
    if(productType.attr('checked') == 1)
    {
        productSelect.prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else
    {
        productSelect.prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Comment: например потому, что функция `change` принимает **только один** параметр

Comment: Обновил, добавил еще вариант. Но с ни вообще не пашет

Comment: значение атрибута **всегда** строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно увидеть в документации к [методу `change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/): этот метод принимает только одну функцию обработчик.

Поэтому при передаче двух функций одна будет просто проигнорирована.

Для исправления, в одном обработчике просто присваивать значение свойства checked радио-кнопки. Например так:

```
productType.change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    productSelect.prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

---

Как верно замечено в соседнем ответе, событие *change* срабатывает срабатывает только на текущем элементе.

Так как используется две радио-кнопки, то в обработчике change достаточно просто проверить `id` изменяемой кнопки, если это кнопка отвечающая за деактивирование - то нужно ставить значение `false`, иначе `true`.

Например так:

```js
var productType = $('[name=radio1]');
var productSelect = $('#product_select');
productType.change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  productSelect.prop('disabled', this.id === 'is_group_2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='product_select' disabled>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="is_group_1" />Вкл
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="is_group_2" checked/>Выкл
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) принимает только одну функцию обработчик. К тому же, при переключении на другой `radio`, событие change срабатывает только для него, для уже отмеченного `radio` событие не вызывается.

Поэтому предлагаю следующий вариант: добавить к нужным `radio` общий класс и пометить дополнительно классами `"on" и "off"`, после чего повесить обработчик события change на класс, а не на id `radio` и проверять в обработчике наличие класса `off` функцией [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```js
var productType = $('.selectSwitcher');
    var productSelect = $('#product_select');
    productType.change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      productSelect.prop('disabled', $(this).hasClass('off'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = 'product_select' disabled>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="selectSwitcher on" id="is_group_1"/> Вкл<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="selectSwitcher off" id="is_group_2"/> Выкл
</div>
```